# Jinja2 parsing a JSON object, can't get a values from it

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I'm trying to parse a string. I have two variants:

1. Not loaded with json.loads()
2. loaded

They look like:

1.

```
{"ticket_info": {"ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK", "ticket_status": 1, "ticket_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:40 PM", "ticket_replied": false, "ticket_reply_message": null, "ticket_issued_by": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7", "ticket_issued_to": "1e76b45c-67cd-4100-ae43-d8adf85d4362"}, "messages": [{"msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK", "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e8890a5dce", "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7", "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:48 PM", "msg": "test_msg1"}, {"msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK", "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e88f0a7dce", "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7", "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:59 PM", "msg": "test_msg3"}, {"msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK", "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad05-80e8890a5dce", "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7", "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:49 PM", "msg": "test_msg2"}]}
```

2. `{'ticket_info': {'ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'ticket_status': 1, 'ticket_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:40 PM', 'ticket_replied': False, 'ticket_reply_message': 'None', 'ticket_issued_by': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'ticket_issued_to': '1e76b45c-67cd-4100-ae43-d8adf85d4362'}, 'messages': [{'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e8890a5dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:48 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg1'}, {'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e88f0a7dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:59 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg3'}, {'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad05-80e8890a5dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:49 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg2'}]}`

My Python code:

```
if ticket:
    "~ Engine for JSON data processing ~"

    _ticket_data_ = _tickets_.get_ticket(ticket.ticket_id)
    ticket_data = json.loads(str(_ticket_data_.replace('null', '"None"')))


    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Main profile',
                           template='dashboard-template',
                           current_user=current_user,
                           ticket_data=ticket_data,
                           body="You are now logged in!")
```

When I pass the loaded one I can get these results:

The Json I passed in HTML is:

`{'ticket_info': {'ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'ticket_status': 1, 'ticket_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:40 PM', 'ticket_replied': False, 'ticket_reply_message': 'None', 'ticket_issued_by': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'ticket_issued_to': '1e76b45c-67cd-4100-ae43-d8adf85d4362'}, 'messages': [{'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e8890a5dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:48 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg1'}, {'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e88f0a7dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:59 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg3'}, {'msg_ticket_id': 'HGAS52GH98JK', 'msg_id': '2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad05-80e8890a5dce', 'msg_sender': '65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7', 'msg_date': 'Wed, 13 May 2020 20:49 PM', 'msg': 'test_msg2'}]}`

I parse it with:

```
{% if ticket_data %} 
    {% for ticket in ticket_data["ticket_info"] %}
      <h3>variables... {{ ticket }}</h3>
      {% if ticket["ticket_issued_to"] == current_user.public_id %}
    <!-- I cannot reach this or any other variable with ticket[ANYVAR]... -->
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Results:

```
variables... ticket_id
variables... ticket_status
variables... ticket_date
variables... ticket_replied
variables... ticket_reply_message
variables... ticket_issued_by
variables... ticket_issued_to
```

But when I try to reach a value inside a for loop with:

```
<h2> Receiver - {{ticket["ticket_issued_to"]}}</h2>
```

I just get the value as blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually trying to get value from the wrong place of Dict.

Let's walk through the dictionary and see where actually the code is looking.

This is your ticket data:

```
{
  "ticket_info": {
    "ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
    "ticket_status": 1,
    "ticket_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:40 PM",
    "ticket_replied": false,
    "ticket_reply_message": null,
    "ticket_issued_by": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
    "ticket_issued_to": "1e76b45c-67cd-4100-ae43-d8adf85d4362"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
      "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e8890a5dce",
      "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
      "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:48 PM",
      "msg": "test_msg1"
    },
    {
      "msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
      "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad09-80e88f0a7dce",
      "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
      "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:59 PM",
      "msg": "test_msg3"
    },
    {
      "msg_ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
      "msg_id": "2d4c0968-337b-4401-ad05-80e8890a5dce",
      "msg_sender": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
      "msg_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:49 PM",
      "msg": "test_msg2"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is your ticket_data["ticket_info"]:

```
{
  "ticket_id": "HGAS52GH98JK",
  "ticket_status": 1,
  "ticket_date": "Wed, 13 May 2020 20:40 PM",
  "ticket_replied": false,
  "ticket_reply_message": null,
  "ticket_issued_by": "65313696-d0a0-4019-8f89-e5e8ab01d6b7",
  "ticket_issued_to": "1e76b45c-67cd-4100-ae43-d8adf85d4362"
}
```

when you run below loop:

```
{% for ticket in ticket_data["ticket_info"] %}
```

It actually goes through the list of keys of ticket_info dict and that's why while printing the ticket variable in the loop you are actually getting the list of keys in the output so if you want to get the value you should try this:

```
{% if ticket_data %} 
    {% for ticket in ticket_data["ticket_info"] %}
      <h3>variable key... {{ ticket }}</h3>
      <h3>variable value... {{ ticket_data["ticket_info"][ticket] }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You will get both the key and value using the above code. You can modify your "if" statement accordingly.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: But when I try to get this value - ` {{ ticket_data["ticket_info"][ticket]["ticket_issued_to"] }} ` I Don't get anything and for loop is running as much times as how many values there is

Comment: If you are running it in the loop then ticket_data["ticket_info"][ticket] should be enough to get some value because ticket_data["ticket_info"] is a Dict and ticket is the key of it.